# Simple paragraph break

Tags: dashcode

I am trying to make a simple paragraph break in my text file (name.js) so that when the iphone pulls the information (name.js) there is not one big run on paragraph. I have looked and looked and cannot find this information can you help me project is due at this time...

Answer (score 0):

I am away from my machine so i cannot check but try a \n  or \r\n

Well it had to be one or the other it'

```
<br />
```

i just hacked a widget and tried it. By the way i am assuming you are doing some like the following

```
// localised strings
  var backString_01 = "World Second <br />offers unbeatable exchange rates and exceptional service for foreign exchange and international payments";
```

then outputting to the document with

```
document.getElementById('services_headline').innerHTML = backString_01;
```

With the element in the html something like ....

```
<div id="services_headline" apple-part="com.apple.Dashcode.part.text" class="apple-text apple-no-children" apple-default-image-visibility="hidden" apple-text-overflow="ellipsis"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this in the javascript:

```
var pageBreak = document.createElement("/p");
document.getElementsByTagName("tagToInsertBreakAfter")[0].appendChild(pageBreak);
```

Comment: Where does this go? Not in my (name.js) file is it?

Comment: I am using Dashcode... I tried dropping it in the main.js file then calling it from the (name.js) and I got an error.

Comment: I don't know much about Dashcode or iPhone development... but the code snippet I gave you is javascript that will generate the html for a pagebreak after a specific tag you identify.  And yes it would probably go in your name.js.

Comment: Ok Thank Halks... Do you know where to get additional javascript codes for Dashcode / iPhone development..